# BeanUtils converting java.util.Map to nested bean

Tags: java, javabeans, pojo, apache-commons-beanutils

I have a Java bean which has a field which in turn is another bean

```
public class BeanOne {
   private String fieldOne;
   private BeanTwo fieldTwo;

   public String getFieldOne() {return this.fieldOne;}  
   public void setFieldOne(String fieldOne){this.fieldOne = fieldOne}

   public BeanTwo getFieldTwo() {return this.fieldTwo;}  
   public void setFieldTwo(BeanTwo fieldTwo){this.fieldTwo = fieldTwo}
}

public class BeanTwo {
   private String fieldOne;

   public String getFieldOne() {return this.fieldOne;}  
   public void setFieldOne(String fieldOne){this.fieldOne = fieldOne}
}
```

I am trying to pass a map to BeanUtils to try and convert the following map into BeanOne

```
Map beanOneMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
beanOneMap.put("fieldOne", "fieldOneValue");
Map beanTwoMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
beanTwoMap.put("fieldOne", "fieldOneValue");
beanOneMap.put("fieldTwo", beanTwoMap);

BeanOne beanOne = new BeanOne();
BeanUtils.populate(beanOne, beanOneMap);
```

But it throws an error saying - `Cannot invoke BeanOne.setFieldTwo on bean class 'class Bean' - argument type mismatch - had objects of type "java.util.HashMap" but expected signature "BeanTwo"`

How can I use BeanUtils to correctly populate the inner bean ?

Comment: Check BeanOne.java's fieldTwo of type BeanTwo.. But setters and getter of Type String..

Comment: thank you. i had accidentally wrote that. fixed it now.

Comment: I do not believe this is possible. Populate `BeanTwo`, then populate `BeanOne` with that.

Answer (score 12):

You should use Spring's BeanWrapper class. It supports nested properties, and optionally create inner beans for you:

```
BeanOne one = new BeanOne();
BeanWrapper wrapper = PropertyAccessorFactory.forBeanPropertyAccess(one);
wrapper.setAutoGrowNestedPaths(true);

Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("fieldOne", "fieldOneValue");
map.put("fieldTwo.fieldOne", "fieldOneValue");

wrapper.setPropertyValues(map);

assertEquals("fieldOneValue", one.getFieldOne());
BeanTwo two = one.getFieldTwo();
assertNotNull(two);
assertEquals("fieldOneValue", two.getFieldOne();
```

The killer feature of auto-creating inner beans is achieved thanks to `wrapper.setAutoGrowNestedPaths(true)`. The default value is false, which means you will get a `NullValueInNestedPathException` if an element in the property path is null.

Comment: I use spring mvc in my project, and this solution is the best for me. Think about spring mvc auto bind JSON to your bean, spring works very well. So, this `convert map to bean` solution is really really good.

Answer (score 7):

Here we go you can do like this....

BeanOne.java

```
import java.util.Map;

public class BeanOne {
    private String fieldOne;
    private Map<String,BeanTwo> fieldTwo;
    public Map<String, BeanTwo> getFieldTwo() {
        return fieldTwo;
    }

    public void setFieldTwo(Map<String, BeanTwo> fieldTwo) {
        this.fieldTwo = fieldTwo;
    }

    public String getFieldOne() {
        return this.fieldOne;
    }

    public void setFieldOne(String fieldOne) {
        this.fieldOne = fieldOne;
    }
}
```

BeanTwo.java

```
public class BeanTwo {
    private String fieldOne;

    public String getFieldOne() {
        return this.fieldOne;
    }

    public void setFieldOne(String fieldOne) {
        this.fieldOne = fieldOne;
    }
}
```

Tester.java

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils;

public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException,
            InvocationTargetException {
        Map beanTwoMap = new HashMap();
        beanTwoMap.put("fieldOne", "fieldOne2222Value");
        Map beanOneMap = new HashMap();
        beanOneMap.put("fieldOne", "fieldOneValue");
        beanOneMap.put("fieldTwo", beanTwoMap);
        BeanOne beanOne = new BeanOne();
        BeanUtils.populate(beanOne, beanOneMap);
        System.out.println(beanOne.getFieldOne());
        System.out.println(beanOne.getFieldTwo().get("fieldOne"));
    }

}
```

output will be:-

```
fieldOneValue
fieldOne2222Value
```