# How to convert map with flat properties (prop1.prop2.prop3) into POJO

Tags: java, jackson, type-conversion, mapping, pojo

I have following usecase:

I'm having map with properties:

```
Map <String, String[]> args = new HashMap(){{
put("requester.firstName", "Alice");
put("requester.lastName", "Smith");
put("requester.address", "Glasgow Av");
put("publication.type", "print");
put("publication.subtype", "book");
}};
```

I need to convert it to this pojo

```
public class WebRequest{
private Requester requester;
private Publication publication;
}

class Requester{
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String address;
}

class Publication{
private String type;
private String subType;
}
```

Can I use Jackson, to run the conversion? If not, what is the best suitable library for this?

Thanks,

Nadiia

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the `BeanUtils` of apache common. That framework is capable to map from a `Map` to a bean almost instantly.

```
Map<String,String> yourMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
yourMap.put("name", "Joan");
yourMap.put("age", "30");

YourBean p = new YourBean();

try {
    BeanUtils.populate(p, yourMap);
}  catch (Throwable e) {
    //do something...
}
```

What I'm not sure about is whether it automatically recognizes nested objects and corresponding properties but maybe you are able to do this di-visioning manually (by offering 2 maps, etc).

More information can be found here [BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.2/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/package-summary.html#conversion.beanutils)

Answer (score 0):

I found here on StackOverflow excellent solution for my problem. Similar problem,
[BeanUtils converting java.util.Map to nested bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21720128/beanutils-converting-java-util-map-to-nested-bean)

One of the answers was perfect:

You should use Spring's BeanWrapper class. It supports nested properties, and optionally create inner beans for you:

```
BeanOne one = new BeanOne();
BeanWrapper wrapper = PropertyAccessorFactory.forBeanPropertyAccess(one);
wrapper.setAutoGrowNestedPaths(true);

Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("fieldOne", "fieldOneValue");
map.put("fieldTwo.fieldOne", "fieldOneValue");

wrapper.setPropertyValues(map);

assertEquals("fieldOneValue", one.getFieldOne());
BeanTwo two = one.getFieldTwo();
assertNotNull(two);
assertEquals("fieldOneValue", two.getFieldOne();
```

I hope it will help somebody with similar problem.